# How to use Snippets in vscode to define python function input parameter comments (parameter name and type)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

For example, when I type """ under the signature of a python function, it triggers the automatic parsing of the function parameter comments, which contain information about the definition, type, default value, etc. of the input and output parameters of the function.  I don't want to use a third-party plugin to do this, I want to use [vscode's own snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) to do it.

```
def myfun(a,b,c=1,d="defaultvalue"):
"""


Parameters
----------
a : TYPE
    DESCRIPTION.
b : TYPE
    DESCRIPTION.
c : TYPE, optional
    DESCRIPTION. The default is 1.
d : TYPE, optional
    DESCRIPTION. The default is "defaultvalue".

Returns
-------
str
    DESCRIPTION.

"""
return "test"
```

[image]

Comment: snippets don't have access to the previous line(s) content, without an extension that has a completion provider you will not get it to work, where do you get the `TYPE` of a variable, in the example none is defined, the example function returns something so it should also analyze the whole function to find the result

Comment: have a look at the extension `Hypersnips`, typing the `def name(a,b):` is the "input" of the snippet after starting it with a prefix, look at the box example on the extension page

Comment: The above example is the [spyder IDE](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) automatically generated function comments, if not use extensions, vscode(snippets) can automatically generate it would be good.

Comment: I know this isn't using vscode(snippets) but I came across the [Python Docstring Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=njpwerner.autodocstring) extension which does exactly what you want.